# TimerTask concurrency issue

Tags: java, concurrency, timertask

I have a Timer that should say to my application that its time to read some data

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                    states[PICK_FRAME_STATE]=true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 1000/fRate);
```

the states array its `final boolean[]`

Where the data its read during a draw loop

```
  if(lastFrame!=null&&states[PICK_FRAME_STATE]){
      father.image(lastFrame, 500, 200,VRes,HRes);
      buff.add(lastFrame);
      //states[PICK_FRAME_STATE]=false;
      System.out.println(is++);
  }
```

However the instruction

`states[PICK_FRAME_STATE]=false`;

if its not commented makes the application crash.

I would like to be able to detect when at least `1000/fRate` milliseconds are passed in a loop that its, in general, more fast than `1000/fRate`.

I think `TimerTask` grants exactly at least one execution every time interval but I am getting concurrency issues(unsurprisingly) with this implementation, any workaround?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.opengl.Texture.copyBufferFromSource(Texture.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at processing.video.Capture.read(Unknown Source)
    at aaa.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:78)
    at aaa.view.video.CameraWindow.render(CameraWindow.java:99)
    at aaa.desktop.view.ProfileView.render(ProfileView.java:55)
    at aaa.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:385)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

(edit from answer by Tobias)

```
long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
public void draw() {
  if (video.available()) {
    video.read(); // Read a new video frame
    lastFrame=video;
  }
  if(lastFrame!=null && System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000){
      time = System.currentTimeMillis();
      father.image(lastFrame, 500, 200,VRes,HRes);
      buff.add(lastFrame);
      System.out.println(is++);
  }
}
```

works even tough it gives 3 exception like before, but then all its fine. strangely if i comment the line

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

i get no exception

```
0 <=first frame added
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.opengl.Texture.copyBufferFromSource(Texture.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at processing.video.Capture.read(Unknown Source)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:81)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.render(CameraWindow.java:101)
    at ygg.desktop.view.ProfileView.render(ProfileView.java:55)
    at ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:385)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.opengl.Texture.copyBufferFromSource(Texture.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at processing.video.Capture.read(Unknown Source)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:81)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.render(CameraWindow.java:101)
    at ygg.desktop.view.ProfileView.render(ProfileView.java:55)
    at ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:385)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.opengl.Texture.copyBufferFromSource(Texture.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at processing.video.Capture.read(Unknown Source)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:81)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.render(CameraWindow.java:101)
    at ygg.desktop.view.ProfileView.render(ProfileView.java:55)
    at ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:385)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.opengl.Texture.copyBufferFromSource(Texture.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at processing.video.Capture.read(Unknown Source)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:81)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.render(CameraWindow.java:101)
    at ygg.desktop.view.ProfileView.render(ProfileView.java:55)
    at ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:385)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.opengl.Texture.copyBufferFromSource(Texture.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at processing.video.Capture.read(Unknown Source)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:81)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.render(CameraWindow.java:101)
    at ygg.desktop.view.ProfileView.render(ProfileView.java:55)
    at ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:385)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.opengl.Texture.copyBufferFromSource(Texture.java:859)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at processing.video.Capture.read(Unknown Source)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:81)
    at ygg.view.video.CameraWindow.render(CameraWindow.java:101)
    at ygg.desktop.view.ProfileView.render(ProfileView.java:55)
    at ygg.desktop.view.MainView.draw(MainView.java:385)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2386)
    at processing.opengl.PJOGL$PGLListener.display(PJOGL.java:862)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:665)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:649)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1289)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1119)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:994)
    at javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1300)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
1 
2
3
```

ecc... each 1000 ms

Comment: Show stack trace of crash please.

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with concurrency? What happens in `Texture.java:859`?

Comment: at aaa.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:78) its where the application tries to read camera input(before the reported code), which seems unrelated to the issue, but if i comment the concurrent write all works, else i get the reported exception over and over every loop. Lines above aaa.view.video.CameraWindow.draw(CameraWindow.java:78) are processing libraries

Comment: @Yggdrasil can you post the exception stack trace with the new version please?

Comment: sorry, apparently the problem was a bug in the processing libraries... that somehow cannot deal with doing the first loops without printing the image(dont really know why). thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

//...

// draw call:
if(lastFrame != null && System.currentTimeMillis() - time >= 1000){
    // do stuff
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

`// do stuff` is called at maximum every 1000ms. Without any TimerTask magic.

## Edit

Try this for capturing "missed" frames:

```
private long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

//...

// draw call:
long delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
if(lastFrame != null && delta >= 1000){
    int framesMissed = delta / 1000; // rounds to full seconds
    for(int i=0;i<framesMissed;i++){
        // do stuff for each missed frame/picture
    }
    // apply "overlap" so we actually carry the right result to the next call
    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - (delta-(1000*framesMissed));
}
```

`// do stuff` will now be called for each second that has passed, disregarding the frequency of the draw calls (they can be faster or slower than 1000ms)

Comment: works fine thanks, i added an edit to question. The TimerTask has the advantage(i think) that for example if time was to be 2000+(because of some slow in the camera thread) then the next 2 loop should record 2 frames, granting a time/frames consistency(well not with my implementation tough xd)

Comment: fine thanks, i voted the answer but they dont let me upvote you because low rep (new user)